# Change pricing tiers in Stripe based on team size/count

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I want to base my pricing tiers in Stripe for when a company signs up like so:

Number of members in a company:

- 0-200: $50/month
- 201-500: $100/month
- 501+: $150/month

Whenever a company adds or removes a member, if they enter into one of those tiers their subscription price should change.

Now I could set up 3 different subscription plans and in my code programmatically upgrade or downgrade a company's subscription based on the members they add or remove. My question is can this be done automatically by passing the company's member size to stripe and on stripe's side change the tier without my code doing the logic of changing subscription plans?

So instead of 3 subscription plans just have one but change the tier based on member size. Stripe allows you to setup tier pricing with quantities but it doesn't work quite in this way they have it where each quantity represents its own plan and goes down in price per plan as the number of plans increase. Not what I want. Also I looked at volume/meter pricing and not actually sure if that's what I want.

Any help is much appreciated!